# PHP AWS S3 SDK retry on network connections errors

Tags: php, http, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS SDK V3 for PHP. Sometimes when I make calls to AWS S3 I get errors like 400 errors `Bad Request RequestTimeout (client): Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period` due to network problem even when the object I'm trying to interact with is there. What I need to do is to implement a retry mechanism. I wonder if we can do it simply with an option in the AWS SDK to specify the number of times we want a retry after an error. 
I know that I can do that with simple try catch and retry, but I'm thinking may be the SDK already provides a much cleaner way to do that.
I already found static function `Middleware::retry()` but I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the number of retries when constructing a new instance of any AWS service client class:

```
$client = new Aws\EC2\Ec2Client([
    'region'  => 'eu-central-1',
    'retries' => 3
]);
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/configuration.html#retries

Comment: I checked the document and found that there's already a default number of retries which is `3`. But how I can specify a sleep time (a delay before retrying) because it seems to retry right a away and it doesn't give time to the service to come back. I used the `delay` option just like `retries` but it doesn't seem to take effect.

Comment: I added the config param `'http'=>['delay'=> 5000]` . I thought it would be the delay time between two retries but it ended up to be the time to execute the whole HTTP request even when there's no connection problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this,

```
public function get_s3_connection(){
       $sdk = new \Aws\Sdk([
            'region' => 'us-east-1',
            'version' => 'latest',
            'credentials' => $credentials
        ]);

       $s3_connection = $sdk->createS3([
            'retries' => 3,
            'http' => [
                'connect_timeout' => 15,
                'timeout' => 20
            ],
            'endpoint' => 'https://bucket.0123xyz.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
        ]);
        return $s3_connection;
}
```

In the above code the `retries => 3` means it will try 3 times and then stop trying.
You can also set the timeout and connect_timeout as show above.

You can also retry manually by surrounding the method with do-while loop, as shown below,

```
public function s3_connect_with_retry($total_retry = 3){
     $retry_count = 0;
     $do_retry = false;
     do{
        try{
            $s3_connection = $this->get_s3_connection();
       }catch(Exception $exception){
           $retry_count++;
           $do_retry = true;
       }
       }while($total_retry < $retry && $do_retry == true;);
}
```

When the connection breaks and throws exception the `$do_retry` value will become true and the `$retry_count` will increase. based on the `$do_retry` flag the retry happens until the `$total_retry` count is reached.